# yii : strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Tags: php, yii

Problem: `strcmp()` expects parameter 2 to be string, array given.

This error message occurs when the user updates. User creation is working fine. How can I solve this problem?

I create a `radiobuttonlist` as follow:

```
<div style="height:140px; padding-left: 20px;">
    <div>
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'role'); ?>
        <?php 
            echo $form->radioButtonList(
                $model, 
                'role', 
                $roles,
                array(
                    'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align:middle '), // add this code
                )
            );
        ?> 
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'role'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

`$roles` is coming from controller by:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isSuperuser) {
    $all_roles=new RAuthItemDataProvider('roles', array('type'=>2, ));
    $roles = $all_roles->fetchData();
} else {
    $roles = Authitem::model()->findAll('type=2 And name<>:name',array(':name'=>'Superadmin'));
        
    $original_roles = Authassignment::model()->findAll('userid=:userid',array(':userid'=>$model->id));
    $model->role    = CHtml::listData($original_roles, 'itemname', 'itemname'); 
            
    $roles = CHtml::listData($roles,'name','name');
    //$model->role = array_merge($original_roles, $roles);
    //$model->role = (array)$original_roles;
    //var_dump($model->role);
    //die;
    $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'profile'=>$profile,
        'roles'=>$roles,
        //'department'=>$department,
        //'designation'=>$designation,
        'original_roles'=>$original_roles,
    ));
}
```

When I use as `$form->checkBoxList`, it working correctly.

Comment: Where's the offending `strcmp`?

Comment: when I use $form->radioButtonList, strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given <<< PHP warning come out. when I use $form->checkBoxList the form is working correctly. I want to use $form->radioButtonList.

Comment: show code where you use `strcmp`

Comment: Sergey<< I didn't use strcmp at anywhere. But I think yii is using it. But I don't know where it is. sorry to define that I'm using yii framework.

Answer (score 0):

The fourth param you set when you call your [RadioButtonList()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeRadioButtonList-detail) should be an array of key value pairs, not an array of arrays. I'm not sure you can define 'labelOptions' as it's not an HTML tag.

The error is occurring because Yii is expecting your final array to be key value pairs, and instead sees that 'labelOptions' is an array, not a string.

Try something like;

```
echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'role', $roles,
    array('style'=>'display:inline; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align:middle '),
);
```

Or even better use css;

```
.myRadioButtonList { display:inline; padding-right: 1em; vertical-align:middle }
```

and in the view:

```
echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'role', $roles,
    array('class'=>'myRadioButtonList'),
);
```

Comment: No, can't solve. Same error. I tried K.O. this error without any css like this ***echo $form->radioButtonList($model, 'role', $roles);*** But I can't :(

Comment: very odd, which line is the stcmp() error? in [CHtml.php  radioButtonList() method](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php#L957)?

Comment: thought so, ok for some reason [this method](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php#L2135) is returning a string, which is shouldn't be. That value is then passed to the [readioButtonList()](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php#L942) method... very odd, can you edit the CHtml.php file to var dump along the route every so often so you can trace where `$select` in the radioButtonList() method becomes an array?

Comment: also, might be an idea to move this comments discussion to chat, might be easier to follow? :)

Comment: I've not done to discuss at chat. Let me try. Pls tell me when can I start.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a Button List with `$form->radioButtonList()`, yii generates an extra hidden input field. That works fine if you submit a form in the standard manner.

However, when you serialize a form for ajax submission, `.serialize()` picks up the hidden `<input>`. It then has two values for said radio-button field, and proceeds to create an array rather than a single value.

This causes the error:  **strcmp() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given**

The best solution is to prevent yii from generating the hidden `<input>`. This may easily be achieved by adding

```
array('uncheckValue'=>NULL)
```

as a HTMLoption. For example:

```
$form->radioButtonList($model,'viewer_format', $options, array('uncheckValue'=>NULL));
```

Answer (score -1):

your render need 2 parameters, first the view and next the parameters
example:  return $this->render('view', []);